# Strip Characters form URL using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, strip

I have a few comma-separated URLs as shown below.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=17kTY2b3XvERC4wqZnLt7sVwMe8ZoDZUD, https://drive.google.com/open?id=1En1tNNLEgz5JiIk2GJnjNb_bhk23YJb2, https://drive.google.com/open?id=2En1tNNLEgz5JiIk3GJnjNb_bhk23YJb2

I need to get just the IDs (Example: 17kTY2b3XvERC4wqZnLt7sVwMe8ZoDZUD) from it in an array.

I'm a rookie coder and would appreciate it if someone can help me with the code.

Answer (score 5):

Use the URL parsing library built-in to the browser. Don't attempt to use regular expressions to pick apart the URL because you don't have to (and you might end up getting it wrong).

```
var u = new URL("https://drive.google.com/open?id=2En1tNNLEgz5JiIk3GJnjNb_bhk23YJb2");
console.log(u.searchParams.get('id'));
> "2En1tNNLEgz5JiIk3GJnjNb_bhk23YJb2"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use string.split("?id=") and get the second element from the array returned (element 0 for everything to the left, 1 for the right)

E.G:

```
<script>
    var myArray = ["https://drive.google.com/open?id=17kTY2b3XvERC4wqZnLt7sVwMe8ZoDZUD", 
    "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1En1tNNLEgz5JiIk2GJnjNb_bhk23YJb2", 
    "https://drive.google.com/open?id=2En1tNNLEgz5JiIk3GJnjNb_bhk23YJb2"];

    for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++)
    {
        var result = myArray[i].split("?id=")[1];
        console.log(result);
    }
</script>
```